# Getting am error in Appmanifest.xml file while build

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I am porting the unity game in windows store game so have generated the windows store build from unity4.2.2 when i build the unity build solution from visual studio 2013 on windows 8.1 platform (retargetted the solution to 8.1 ) i am getting error at following line in AppManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"    xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2012/build" IgnorableNamespaces="build">

  <Identity Name="FIR_gameA2" Publisher="CN=circ" Version="1.0.0.0"ProcessorArchitecture="arm" />
     <Properties>
    <DisplayName>SHOOT</DisplayName>
      <PublisherDisplayName>circ</PublisherDisplayName>
     <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
     </Properties>
```

following are the errors and warnings i  am getting

> Error 1   File content does not conform to specified schema. The 'Name'
>   attribute is invalid - The value 'FIR_gameA2' is invalid according to
>   its datatype
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_PackageName' - The
>   Pattern constraint failed.    E:\Windows Games Store\firshootXAMLC#\SAB
>   Ka Shoot\bin\ARM\Debug\AppxManifest.xml   10  13  SAB Ka Shoot
>   Warning   2   The 'Name' attribute is invalid - The value 'FIR_gameA2' is
>   invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_PackageName' - The
>   Pattern constraint failed.    E:\Windows Games Store\firshootXAMLC#\SAB
>   Ka Shoot\bin\ARM\Debug\AppxManifest.xml   10  19  Miscellaneous Files
>   Warning   3   The element 'Package' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest' has invalid child
>   element 'Metadata' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2012/build'. E:\Windows
>   Games Store\firshootXAMLC#\SAB Ka
>   Shoot\bin\ARM\Debug\AppxManifest.xml  71  4   Miscellaneous Files

Comment: Have you tried removing `**` from `Name="FIR_gameA2"**` in `<Identity />`?

Comment: ** is part of formatting ...it is not present in my code

Comment: But why it's outside of double quotes ?

Comment: i have edited the code....this is the actual code.

Comment: Try to compile after removing `**`.

Comment: same error after recompiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Package manifest schema reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211453.aspx) entry on [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211441.aspx):

### Name

```
 string between 3 and 50 characters in length that consists of alpha-numeric, period, and dash characters.
```

### Remarks

```
Important  

For the Name and ResourceID strings, the following rules must be followed:

Allowed Input Characters = ASCII subset
    Uppercase letters (U+0041 thru U+005A)
    Lowercase letters (U+0061 thru U+007A)
    Numbers (U+0030 thru U+0039)
    Dot (U+002E)
    Dash (U+002D)
Prohibited Strings
    Cannot equal…
        ".", "..", "con", "prn", "aux", "nul", "com1", "com2", "com3", "com4", "com5", "com6", "com7", "com8", "com9", "lpt1", "lpt2", "lpt3", "lpt4", "lpt5", "lpt6", "lpt7", "lpt8", "lpt9"
    Cannot begin with…
        "con.", "prn.", "aux.", "nul.", "com1.", "com2.", "com3.", "com4.", "com5.", "com6.", "com7.", "com8.", "com9.", "lpt1.", "lpt2.", "lpt3.", "lpt4.", "lpt5.", "lpt6.", "lpt7.", "lpt8.", "lpt9.", "xn--"
    Cannot end with…
        "."
    Cannot contain…
        ".xn--"
```

Your `Name` include the 'underscore' character `_` (U+005F), which is not a valid character. Remove it, possibly replacing it with either the Dash `-` or Dot`.`.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: but now i am getting platform error        Error 1 Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package FIRgameA2 because the package requires architecture ARM, but this computer has architecture x64. (0x80073cf3)

Comment: and when i build with x64 architecture type then i got 3 errors                ,Error 6 The type or namespace name 'UnityPlayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error 7 The type or namespace name 'WinRTBridge' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Windows Games Store\shoot d3lc c#\Shoot\App.cs 17 11 Shoot
Error 8 The type or namespace name 'AppCallbacks' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: That's good, different errors are coming up regarding the actual contents of the app instead of the wrapping (manifest). You can ask a new question about those issues though.

Comment: its solved i installed unity 4.3.4 and made fresh build from it (d3dc++) it is working fine !!!